# How to extract a part of the string to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that contains data like

**Dummy data:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["Lyreco A-Type small 2i",
"Lyreco C-Type small 4i",
"Lyreco N-Part medium", 
"Lyreco AKG MT 4i small",
"Lyreco AKG/ N-Type medium 4i",
"Lyreco C-Type medium 2i",
"Lyreco C-Type/ SNU medium 2i",
"Lyreco K-part small 4i",
"Lyreco K-Part medium", 
"Lyreco SNU small 2i",
"Lyreco C-Part large 2i",
"Lyreco N-Type large 4i"])
```

I want to create an extra column that strips the data and gives you the required part of the string(see below) in each row.
The extracted column should look like this

```
Column_1                      Column_2
Lyreco A-Type small 2i         A-Type
Lyreco C-Type small 4i         C-Type
Lyreco N-Part medium           N-Part
Lyreco STU MT 4i small         STU MT
Lyreco AKG/ N-Type medium 4i   AKG/ N-Type
Lyreco C-Type medium 2i        C-Type
Lyreco C-Type/ SNU medium 2i   C-Type/ SNU
Lyreco K-part small 4i         K-part
Lyreco K-Part medium           K-Part
Lyreco SNU small 2i            SNU
Lyreco C-Part large 2i         C-Part
Lyreco N-Type large 4i         N-Type
```

How can I extract column 2 from the first column?

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "the centre part of the string"?

Comment: @alec_djinn The extracted string should look like the Column_2. Example for the "centre part" is the column 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the example you posted, it's enough to split the column values and return "the middle" items. You can make a simple function to encapsulate the logic and apply it to the dataframe.

```
from math import floor

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Columns_1':
     ["Lyreco A-Type small 2i",
      "Lyreco C-Type small 4i",
      "Lyreco N-Part medium", 
      "Lyreco AKG MT 4i small",
      "Lyreco AKG/ N-Type medium 4i",
      "Lyreco C-Type medium 2i",
      "Lyreco C-Type/ SNU medium 2i",
      "Lyreco K-part small 4i",
      "Lyreco K-Part medium", 
      "Lyreco SNU small 2i",
      "Lyreco C-Part large 2i",
      "Lyreco N-Type large 4i"
     ]
    }
)


def f(row):
    blocks = row['Columns_1'].split()
    mid_index = 1 if len(blocks) <= 4 else floor(len(blocks)/2)
    return ' '.join(blocks[1:mid_index+1])

df['Columns_2'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
                       Columns_1    Columns_2
0         Lyreco A-Type small 2i       A-Type
1         Lyreco C-Type small 4i       C-Type
2           Lyreco N-Part medium       N-Part
3         Lyreco AKG MT 4i small       AKG MT
4   Lyreco AKG/ N-Type medium 4i  AKG/ N-Type
5        Lyreco C-Type medium 2i       C-Type
6   Lyreco C-Type/ SNU medium 2i  C-Type/ SNU
7         Lyreco K-part small 4i       K-part
8           Lyreco K-Part medium       K-Part
9            Lyreco SNU small 2i          SNU
10        Lyreco C-Part large 2i       C-Part
11        Lyreco N-Type large 4i       N-Type
```

Comment: Some data is missing in column 2 according to your code. Also please check the updated dummy data in the question. If you find any leads let me know :)

Comment: @ar_mm18 Fixed accordingly. This is why it is important to 1) describe the problem very well and 2) include an example that encompasses all cases you may find in the real data.

Comment: Thank you again, I will keep that in mind while posting a question next time. In column 3 of your solution. AKG MT should be the answer. But it is getting skipped. I am unable to include that in an else statement

Comment: @ar_mm18 what about now?

Answer (score 3):

You might find that the following logic works with your data:

```py
df["Column_2"] = df["Column_1"].str.extract(r'\w+ (\S+(?: \S+)*) \b(?:small|medium|large)\b')
```

The above pattern matches from the second term until reaching `small`, `medium`, or `large` keywords.  Here is a working regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ArLnIb/1).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Tim. It works on the dummy data. I will try to reconstruct the code according to the original data I have.

Comment: I have few rows similar to "Lyreco STU/ C-Type medium 2i" these rows are getting extracted as NaN. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: can you send me a link/documentation on how I can write the extract statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.columns = ['column_1']

df["column_2"] = [col.split(" ")[1] for col in df.column_1]
```